# Suppress the date, time and file name in tail output

Tags: unix, sed, awk, grep, tail

I'm doing Xcode dev and am overriding NSLog to dump output to a file so that I can create a useful log window unlike the mess that is currently in Xcode.

I'm using tail ala the terminal to display the file contents like so:

```
tail -f 'iPhone Simulator log.txt'
```

I'm wondering if tail is the wrong cmd to use.  The reason why is that I have no need for the additional information that tail supplies at the beginning of each line, the date, time and filename.

It doesn't appear that suppressing this output is a parameter in tail.

Since the info I don't want ends in "] ", would it be possible to use grep, sed or awk to strip that data out of each line and only dump the rest to the screen so I can get a nice little log of the output I am creating, and nothing more?

TIA,
- Alex

Answer (score 1):

I would use `cut`: http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/cut/

```
tail -f 'iPhone Simulator log.txt' | cut -c 25-
```

(Assuming 24 is the number of characters you want to take away..)

Comment: To be pedantic, that would remove 24 chars.

Comment: Accuracy counts.  It's not pedantic at all.  You rock guys.

Comment: ARGH.  This kills the first 25 chars in any text that bleeds over onto the next line.

Comment: Hey guys. This didn't end up working.  Are you still following the post?

Answer (score 1):

Using sed:

```
tail -f 'iPhone Simulator log.txt' | sed -e 's/^\[[^]]*\]//'
```

The regular expression is:

```
 ^ - beginning of the line
 \[ - start [
 [^]]* - anything but the ]
 \] - end ]
```

Comment: How odd.  That seems right, but does nothing to strip off the chars.  I get exactly the same output.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm.  Inspired by your reply barsju, I did a little sniffing around and this works:

```
tail -f 'iPhone Simulator log.txt' | sed -e 's/.*]/]/g'
```

Though as true with many things regular expression related, I have no idea why.

What is does do though that was unintentional and nice was only delete up to the ] character of from the start of each line.  This means that I get a "bracket space" char sequence at the beginning of each line.  This is nice since this little bit of unintentional design actually nicely indicates new lines of data without taking up too many characters.

Also, this sed + regular expression approach does not nuke any chars at the start of any data that falls onto more than one line.

Thank you again for all your help on this.  I now have my own Xcode console/log readout that Xcode can not screw up.